# Command with optional argument in parentheses and subscript

Tags: macros, subscripts, optional-arguments, arguments

I'd like to have a shorthand command for math that accepts an optional argument which gets put into parentheses if it exists and where the operator also optionally has a subscript.
How can I position the subscript and parentheses how I want it?

I would expect it to look something like this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\op}[1]
{
    \operatorname{\mathrm{J}}(#1)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
    $ \op $ &
    $ \op{a} $ & 
    $ \op_f $ & 
    $ \op_f{a} $ & 
    $ \op{a}_f $ % probably doesn't make sense to use it like this
    \\
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J} $ &
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}(a) $ & 
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f $ & 
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f(a) $ & 
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f(a) $
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The bottom row is how I would want the first code-block to look:
[image: mwe]

Comment: I know the `\op` takes the next character as its argument without curly brackets, hence why it looks so weird, but I don't know why it grabs the brace in the definition

Comment: Is there a real improvement over typing `\op_f(a)`?

Comment: Indeed, I would just use `\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{J}` and normal syntax like `$\begin{array}{*{4}{l}}
  \op      &
  \op(a)   &
  \op_f    &
  \op_f(a)
\end{array}$`.

Comment: Indeed for this operator that works. I have other operators for which the arguments can be taller, like a fraction, hence I'd use `\left(#1\right)` which I am too lazy to write, instead of `(#1)`. And I want to understand a potential answer if there is one for other future scenarios which are in general more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package by using `\NewDocumentCommand`.
I'm not sure if this is such a good idea, however, since an optional brace-delimited argument is very un-LaTeX and it's easy to accidentally pass something in as an argument when you didn't mean to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\op}{e{_}ge{_}}{%
  \operatorname{J}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{(#2)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
    $ \op $ &
    $ \op{a} $ &
    $ \op_f $ &
    $ \op_f{a} $ &
    $ \op{a}_f $ % probably doesn't make sense to use it like this
    \\
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J} $ &
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}(a) $ &
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f $ &
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f(a) $ &
    $ \mathop{\mathrm J}_f(a) $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

In the argument specification, `e{_}` denotes an optional argument preceded by a `_` and `g` denotes an optional `{}`-delimited argument.
`\IfValueT` is used to test if an optional argument was provided and to then act accordingly.
See the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) for more details.

Note that the `g` argument type is not listed at the top because it is only included for backwards compatibility as it “should largely be avoided nowadays as using them [it] in packages leads to inconsistent user interfaces” (from the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

The way you can do that is defining a new command with two paramaters as follows:

```
\newcommand{\op}[2]{\mathrm{J}_{#1}(#2)}
```

and then write the command in the form `\op{subscript}{argument}`. This works good, but in case you want to type only the operator, you must write `\op{}{}` instead of just 
`\op`, and you can't write superscripts directly on the operator (you can't write `\op^2{}{}`, for example).

If you will treat the new operator as a regular operator (I mean, like the `\sin` operator), my recommendation is to write in the preamble

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{\mathrm{J}}
```

and just write the subscript and the argument as with `\sin`, i.e. in the form `\op_f(a)`. This has the advantage that `\op` is treated just like `\sin` so you can write subscrpits and superscripts directly on the operator and omit putting the parenthesis if the argument doesn't exist.