# new command with multiple optional arguments, one of which is bracket size

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

Building on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635277/144086) question and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543318/command-with-optional-argument-in-parentheses-and-subscript) one and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629408/make-command-with-multiple-optional-arguments) one, I'd like to make a new command that has a default behavior for a single primary argument but has two additional arguments that specify (i) bracket size and (ii) subscript.
For example, I have a command

```
\newcommand{\prob}[2][]{\mathsf{P} \ifx\\#1\\\else_{#1}\fi \!\left[#2\right]}
```

for specifying probability operator that I use like `\prob{X\leq x}` or `\prob[X\sim F]{X\leq x}`, but I'd like to modify the bracket size as well.
Is there a nice way to do this with `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`?
Ideally I would use like: `\prob_{X\sim F}[\big]{X\leq x}` and equivalently `\prob[\big]_{X\sim F}{X\leq x}`.

One approach (but requires order and specifying all arguments):

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\LR}{[}{]}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \prob { o m m } {% optional mandatory mandatory: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands
  \IfNoValueTF {#1} {%
    \mathsf{P}_{#2}\LR{#3}%
  }{%
    \mathsf{P}_{#2}\LR[#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: The package [`semantex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex) (disclaimer: I am the author) was created more or less to support syntax like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that a good syntax might be

```
\prob{a=1}                % no subscript, standard size
\prob[\big]{a=1}          % no subscript, \big size
\prob*{a=\frac{1}{2}}     % no subscript, automatic sizing
\prob_{b}{a=1}            % subscript, standard size
\prob_{b}[\big]{a=1}      % subscript, \big size
\prob_{b}*{a=\frac{1}{2}} % subscript, automatic sizing
```

because this is the order in which the various elements naturally appear.

It is not necessary to specify all arguments, because `\prob` can test for the subscript and then pass control to another command that typesets the rest grabbing its argument using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\probargument}{[}{]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\prob}{e{_}}{%
  \mathsf{P}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\probargument
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\prob{a=1}                \\ % no subscript, standard size
\prob[\big]{a=1}          \\ % no subscript, \big size
\prob*{a=\frac{1}{2}}     \\ % no subscript, automatic sizing
\prob_{b}{a=1}            \\ % subscript, standard size
\prob_{b}[\big]{a=1}      \\ % subscript, \big size
\prob_{b}*{a=\frac{1}{2}} % subscript, automatic sizing
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some more `xparse` trickery, you can have an argument like `{a=1|b=1}` to denote conditional probability. Spaces around `|` are ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\probargument}[1]{[}{]}{\probargumentA{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\prob}{e{_}}{%
  \mathsf{P}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\probargument
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\probargumentA}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{%
  \probargumentB#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\probargumentB}{mm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% not conditional
    #1%
  }{% conditional
    #1\;\delimsize|\;#2%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\prob{a=1}                    \\ % no subscript, standard size
\prob[\big]{a=1}              \\ % no subscript, \big size
\prob*{a=\frac{1}{2}}         \\ % no subscript, automatic sizing
\prob_{b}{a=1}                \\ % subscript, standard size
\prob_{b}[\big]{a=1}          \\ % subscript, \big size
\prob_{b}*{a=\frac{1}{2}}     \\ % subscript, automatic sizing
\prob{a=1|b=1}                \\ % no subscript, standard size
\prob[\big]{a=1|b=1}          \\ % no subscript, \big size
\prob*{a=\frac{1}{2}|b=1}     \\ % no subscript, automatic sizing
\prob_{b}{a=1|b=1}            \\ % subscript, standard size
\prob_{b}[\big]{a=1|b=1}      \\ % subscript, \big size
\prob_{b}*{a=\frac{1}{2}|b=1} % subscript, automatic sizing
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! thanks

Comment: @rrrrr I replaced `()` with `[]`.

Comment: maybe this is another question, but would this be easily modified to allow for conditional probabilities, e.g., `\condprob_{b}*{a}{c}` to get P_b[a | c] where the "|" can scale with the brackets?

Comment: @rrrrr Added as wished.

Comment: wow thats amazing!!